# Binding a static global causes error in MonoTouch

Tags: binding, xamarin.ios

I started with a functioning bindings project, but I needed to add a global int for a status flag and I can't get it to bind without error.  I started with the sample code and can't get this to work.

The code I add to my bindings file is:

```
[Static]
interface CameraEffects {
    [Field ("kCameraEffectsZoomFactorKey", "CameraLibrary")]
    NSString ZoomFactorKey { get; }
}
```

I get three errors:

```
obj/Debug/ios/PDFExpert/CameraEffects.g.cs(34,94): error CS0117: `MonoTouch.Constants' does not contain a definition for `CameraLibraryLibrary'
obj/Debug/ios/PDFExpert/CameraEffects.g.cs(34,76): error CS1502: The best overloaded method match for `MonoTouch.ObjCRuntime.Dlfcn.dlopen(string, int)' has some invalid arguments
obj/Debug/ios/PDFExpert/CameraEffects.g.cs(34,76): error CS1503: Argument `#1' cannot convert `object' expression to type `string'
```

If I leave the library off it tried to assign it to another unknown constant.  This seems really screwed up as it is strait from the documentation.

Comment: What exactly happens if you remove the "CameraLibrary" parameter to the Field attribute?

Comment: I get the error MonoTouch.Constants' does not contain a definition for `RDPDFKitLibrary

Comment: Note that the correction was to use the '__Internal' instead of the library name as it is a statically linked library and will then be internal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess this should be bound like this

```
[Static]
interface CameraEffects {
    [Field ("kCameraEffectsZoomFactorKey", "__Internal")]
    NSString ZoomFactorKey { get; }
}
```

This is due to on the final app, the executable and the libxxx.a will be linked and merged together so it should work.

Alex

Answer (score 0):

Another option that allows both assignment and retrieval of the value is to use the internal marshalling that MonoTouch uses.  I got this from a Xamarin support person, notice that this is for manipulating an int, but should be a pattern you can use if you get the right marshalling code.

```
public unsafe static partial class RDPDFGlobal
{
  static readonly IntPtr __Internal_libraryHandle = Dlfcn.dlopen (null, 0);

  public static int RDPDFFeatures {
    get {
      return Dlfcn.GetInt32 (__Internal_libraryHandle, "RDPDFKitEnabledFeatures");
    }
    set {
      var indirect = Dlfcn.dlsym (__Internal_libraryHandle, "RDPDFKitEnabledFeatures");
      if (indirect == IntPtr.Zero)
        throw new Exception ("Field 'RDPDFKitEnabledFeatures' not found.");
        Marshal.WriteInt32 (indirect, value);
    }
}
```

Comment: is it possible to make your example work for my issue here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29390722/how-to-create-binding-for-an-extern-declaration thanks