# how to create binding for an extern declaration

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios, xamarin

I'm trying to create a binding for an iOS library.

When creating a native app with this library, it requires to include a .h header file which declares a global ApplicationKey variable like this:

```
extern const unsigned char ApplicationKey[];
```

and you are supposed to implement it

```
const unsigned char ApplicationKey[] = {0x11, ... };
```

Now, when creating the Xamarin binding for this library, the header file is mapped by Objective Sharpie to

```
partial interface Constants
{
    // extern const unsigned char [] ApplicationKey;
    [Field ("ApplicationKey")]
    byte[] ApplicationKey { get; }
}
```

How to change it to be able to set ApplicationKey from C# code?

Answer (score 1):

Your ApiDefination.cs file should be like this

```
[BaseType (typeof(NSObject))]
    public partial interface Constants
    {
        [Export ("ApplicationKey")]
        TypeOfProperyInNativeCode ApplicationKey { get; set; }
    }
```

in order to access this property create instance of Constant Class of  binding project and access like this

```
Binding.Constant cons= new Binding.Constant();
cons.ApplicationKey  =value;
```

For better understanding you can follow this link http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/advanced_topics/binding_objective-c/Walkthrough_Binding_objective-c_library/

Comment: it gives errors: Error CS0452: The type `byte' must be a reference type in order to use it as type parameter `T' in the generic type or method `Foundation.NSArray.ArrayFromHandle<T>(System.IntPtr)' (CS0452)

Comment: @AndreiN. check the type of this property in native(objective c) code and give same type instead of byte[]

Comment: the native type of the variable is my first post, it's "unsigned char" not sure what reference type to use in C# to make Export atttribute and marshalling work

Comment: [Field] is probably a better choice but it doesn't support byte[]